# iphone: tap button will rotate view

Tags: iphone, rotation, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a problem when trying to manually rotate a view. For example I have a view controller running in landscape, and I have a button on that view. I would like to tap that button to force the view rotate to portrait (upside down portrait). I search but can not find the answer.

Thank for your help

Comment: can you post your code you're having problem with.

Comment: Sorry, it is just the idea, I don't have code yet.

Comment: sorry I reply late, your answer is correct. Thank you very much. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
- (void)buttonPressed {

    // check current orientation
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] != UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {

        // no, the orientation is wrong, we must rotate the UI
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        // setup status bar
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
        // rotate main view, in this sample the view of navigation controller is the root view in main window
        [self.view setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];
        // set size of view
        [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 748, 1024)];

    }

}
```

Comment: how to find out frame size in universal app (iPhone 4/5, iPad/iPad retina/iPad mini)?